# New menu is on wrong menu index page

Tags: menu-item, submenu

I have a Joomla 3.9.24 site on which my mainmenu list has 4 pages.  The mainmenu has 5 top-level menu entries (including Home) with variable numbers of submenus.

I have some single-article menu items which are organized by 2-year groups, and I just added a new "meeting minutes 2021-2022" article and menu item.

The "meetings" entries are organized under a top level entry in mainmenu called "12Y13X NCPC."

The top-level "12Y13X NCPC" menu entry is on page 3 of the mainmenu list.

The "meeting minutes 2021-2022" menu item is on page 4 of the mainmenu list, and I can NOT figure out how to drag it back to page 3 so it will be in its correct place at the bottom of the list of meeting minutes.

It currently shows below a higher-level menu entry with unrelated items under it, which should be below it.

I considered adding a submenu for "meeting minutes" and moving all the 2-year minutes entries under it, but I don't know how to do that.  I have such a mess now and I thought I'd better ask for advice.

My site: rockridgencpc.com

Answer (score 2):

After a break, I figured out how to do this myself.  I'd forgotten that one of the menu search tools is *Parent Item.*  When I chose the correct parent item, it put all the entries under that parent on one page, and I could easily drag the entries around to the order I wanted.  Sorry to take up everyone's time.

Comment: Also - when reordering menu items it's always best to set it to show all items so you don't have to deal with pages